# Oracle Query: How to create unique key on inserting record?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here I have few records.

Id is primary key and auto increment.

Name is Varchar2

Result is Char

**Registration Number is unique key and it is combination of Name-Id.
How can I make my registration number insert in default like this?**

My table looks like:

```
id.  Name.   Result.   Registration Number
___________________________________________

1.   John     P.        John-1
2.   Tom.     P.        Tom-2
3.   John.    P.        John-3
4.   Jerry.   F.        Jerry-4
```

Comment: Is this question about MySQL or Oracle? If it's only for Oracle, then a virtual column could be the answer.

Comment: One possible solution is provided above: virtual column. Another one can be a view where you concatenate two columns. You do not need to store this information, because it can easily be calculated on-the-fly.

Comment: please don't tag oracle database questions with "mysql"

Comment: @JonHeller mysql has virtual columns too

Comment: In this case how can I get it? @JonHeller

Comment: create table t1 ( id number, name varchar2(50), reg varchar2(50) generated always as (name - id) virtual primary key (id));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
CREATE TABLE t1
(
  id  NUMBER  NOT NULL,
  FirstName VARCHAR2(20),
  LastName VARCHAR2(20),
  FullName VARCHAR2(100) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (FirstName || ' ' || LastName || '' || id) VIRTUAL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```